# Rest assured code giving 503 response in java API but working fine in POSTMAN

Tags: java, api, automation, rest-assured

Below is the restassured code:

```
response= given().relaxedHTTPSValidation()
                .contentType(ContentType.URLENC)
                .queryParam("userId", "00528000000OEppAAG")
                .queryParam("orgId", "00D28000000VXOREA4")
                .queryParam("signature", "k8eL+T8QYQGlsT3TDIU9yMxcMgfFl6ROhi1aAgz7P0Y=")
                .queryParam("timestamp", "2016-07-24T14:8:7.798Z")
                .when().urlEncodingEnabled(true).post("https://abc.in/test/testAccountInfo").andReturn();
```

Response from restassured code:

```
<html><body><h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.
</body></html>
```

**Response from Postman is working fine which is very surprising for me**

I tried query param, form param, with content-type, without content-type

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install fiddler & run fiddler and Add this code RestAssured.proxy("localhost", 8888);

Comment: I have the same problem. what should i do then?

Comment: Yes. This helped me..Thanks